# Objective C image processing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-processing

I've googled around for this however the only thing i've properly come across is the simple-image-processing library on Google Code, however i think the project is dead! Does anyone know of any libraries/frameworks, even tutorials on image-processing for iPhone apps?

Comment: Do you have a specific type of image processing you're looking for?  What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: something along the lines of Fat Booth or that one that made you look old, something fun...

Comment: Look into Open CV.  Its a C/C++ based library of image processing routines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has some sample code [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html) that shows how to do some simple image processing like saturation and hue adjustments.